# Read xml value in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to read values of XML elements using a XSL file. My XML file is like:

```
<parameters>
  <parameter id="1338240713" name="Color and structure" xml:lang="eng">
    <value id="1338239139" name="striped" xml:lang="eng"/>
    <value id="1338240721" name="black" xml:lang="eng"/>
    <value id="1338240724" name="12321312" xml:lang="eng"/>
    <value id="1338243166" name="red" xml:lang="eng"/>
  </parameter>
  <parameter id="1338245472" name="State" xml:lang="eng" iaiext:context_id="CONTEXT_STATE">
    <value id="1338245473" name="New" xml:lang="eng" iaiext:context_id="CONTEXT_STATE_NEW"/>
  </parameter>
</parameters>
```

I want read: `parameters > parameter [name "State"] > value [name]`

Comment: I think you should be more specific what you mean by "read". the name would be the xpath expression `parameters/parameter[@name="State"]/@name but this will always be "State"?

Comment: I tried to do:
<xsl:value-of select="parameters/parameter[@name="State"]/value/@name" />
But i have error  "attributes construct error"

Comment: No way out here. What you way you want to read in your question I don't understand. What do you get with the xpath? could you show the context of the xslt? The xpath is context specific in xslt.

Comment: @pasza The input you show us is not well-formed XML (the `iaiext:` prefix is not bound to namespace).

Comment: I have a xml file and on the based on using xslt I have to build a new xml file of my structure

Comment: Please review: [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a **well-formed** XML such as:

**XML**

```
<parameters xmlns:iaiext="http://example.com/iaiext">
    <parameter id="1338240713" name="Color and structure" xml:lang="eng">
        <value id="1338239139" name="striped" xml:lang="eng"/>
        <value id="1338240721" name="black" xml:lang="eng"/>
        <value id="1338240724" name="12321312" xml:lang="eng"/>
        <value id="1338243166" name="red" xml:lang="eng"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter id="1338245472" name="State" xml:lang="eng" iaiext:context_id="CONTEXT_STATE">
        <value id="1338245473" name="New" xml:lang="eng" iaiext:context_id="CONTEXT_STATE_NEW"/>
    </parameter>
</parameters>
```

the following instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/parameters/parameter[@name='State']/value/@name"/>
```

will return the string `"New"`.